# Active ScrollToEnd function of textbox from action

Tags: wpf, textbox, action

I have a `TextBox` in `ScrollViewer` when the text change I run action that should scroll to the end.

Here the `xaml`:

```
<ScrollViewer>
   <TextBox IsReadOnly="True" Text="{Binding SomeText}">
      <i:Interaction.Triggers>
          <i:EventTrigger EventName="TextChanged">
              <ac:ScrollToEndAction/>
          </i:EventTrigger>
      </i:Interaction.Triggers>
   </TextBox>
</ScrollViewer>
```

Here the action:

```
public class ScrollToEndAction : TargetedTriggerAction<FrameworkElement>
{
    protected override void Invoke(object parameter)
    {
        TextBox _textBox = (parameter as TextChangedEventArgs).OriginalSource as TextBox;
        _textBox.ScrollToEnd();
    }
}
```

**It does not work.**

I tried to change the text in action in the following way (**it worked!**):

```
public class ScrollToEndAction : TargetedTriggerAction<FrameworkElement>
{
    protected override void Invoke(object parameter)
    {
        TextBox _textBox = (parameter as TextChangedEventArgs).OriginalSource as TextBox;
        _textBox.Text="Test";
    }
}
```

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally the problem was solved by using:

```
TextBox _textBox = (parameter as TextChangedEventArgs).OriginalSource as TextBox;
_textBox.ScrollToLine(_textBox.LineCount - 1);
```

It's a little weird,

but most importantly that **it works**.